# Illegal instruction in while loop c++

Tags: c++, while-loop, numbers, greatest-common-divisor

I've been assigned to write a program that simplifies a rational number. What I want to do is compute the gcd and then divide the numbers by gcd. But the program returns a very strange error.

The code:

```
void read_rational(int& num, int& den) {
    char bar;
    if (cin >> num >> bar >> den) {
        cout << "hi";
        int a = num;
        int b = den;
        while (b != 0) {
            int r = a%b;
            a = b;
            b = r;
        }
        num /= b;
        den /= b;
    }
}

INPUT: 10/2  OUTPUT: Illegal instruction (core dumped)
INPUT: 90/8  OUTPUT: Illegal instruction (core dumped)
```

I've tried commenting out some bits of the script. The program seems to crash only when the while loop is present. But I can't see what's wrong with it.

Comment: It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming. Further reading: [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: When a program isn't doing what you want it to do, `std::cerr` is your friend. Print out the values as the loop progresses, and figure out where the code is going astray.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Indeed, the issue is the `while` loop. After it finishes, `b` is actually 0, so the divisions after raise these errors.
I think what you want is `a` instead of `b`.